# Neustar Local Validator Error SocketException : Connection Reset

Tags: selenium-webdriver, load-testing

I have been trying to get the Neustar Local-Validator working on my Windows 7 machine however I keep getting  "SocketException : Connection Reset".  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Even a very simple script is failing:

```
var driver = test.openBrowser();
var selenium = driver.getSelenium();

var timeout = 120000;
selenium.setTimeout(timeout);

var tx = test.beginTransaction();

var step = test.beginStep("Homepage", timeout);
 selenium.open("http://www.neustar.biz/");
test.endStep();

test.endTransaction();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might not have the config file setup correctly for your machine.

Update the file C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.wpm\config.properties

An example is below, but you will want to use the correct path based on your machine.

```
FF=C:\\Program\ Files\ (x86)\\Mozilla\ Firefox\\firefox.exe
```

Comment: That took care of it.  I was able to run the command with validator.bat -browser "FF" -keepbrowseronerror "path\to\foo.js"